# The processing order and printing of files with find

Tags: shell-script, find, pipe

This simple BASH script collects msgstrs in a PHP project:

```
#!/bin/sh
TARGET=/path/to/project
LPATH=locale/cy_GB/LC_MESSAGES
POFILE=messages.po
mkdir -p $LPATH
touch $TARGET/$LPATH/$POFILE
cd $TARGET
find . -name '*.php' -print | xargs xgettext -j --from-code=UTF-8 -o $TARGET/$LPATH/$POFILE
```

I have 2 questions:

1. Why doesn't -print list the files it has found - all the docs say it should?
2. Is there any way to specify the order in which find deals with the files?  If I run an equivalent PHP script, it deals with the files in the order they are listed by ls, and then goes into the dirs.  But find seems to do its own thing, with the files jumbled up in no apparent order, and the dirs interspersed with them?

Comment: `ls` by default sorts and find just presents them as they are ordered on disc.

Comment: Its probably my bad English, or me not backquoting `find`. I did not intend to write about how to get them ordered as they are on disc in `ls`, but maybe I misunderstand

Answer (score 4):

`find` has nothing to do with bash, it's a separate utility, probably provided on your system by GNU findutils, if you're running Linux.

`-print` lists the files, but you don't need it -- it's the default. The reason you probably don't "see" them is because its output is being taken by `xargs` on stdin -- it never reaches your terminal. If you want it to go to both, you need to use `tee` or similar (note that if you are getting untrusted filenames, you should *always* use `-print0`, which is not included here because it is an unportable extension):

```
find . -name '*.php' |
    tee >(xargs xgettext -j --from-code=UTF-8 -o "$TARGET/$LPATH/$POFILE")
```

`find` will print the files in the order it finds them, which is unsorted. If you want them to be in order, you need to run through `sort` first.

Comment: Running the output through `sort` might not give the expected order unless [you use a sort order where `/` is first](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/67018/22565).

Answer (score 1):

`find . -name '*.php' -print` does print the list of file names. That's where `xargs` gets its input from.

To avoid nasty surprises with file names containing whitespace and other special characters, use `-print0` and `xargs -0`

```
find . -name '*.php' -print0 | xargs -0 xgettext -j --from-code=UTF-8 -o "$TARGET/$LPATH/$POFILE"
```

or use the `-exec` action instead:

```
find . -name '*.php' -exec xgettext -j --from-code=UTF-8 -o "$TARGET/$LPATH/$POFILE" {} +
```

Beware that if there are too many files, `xgettext` will be executed several times, once per batch of files. This goes whether you used `xargs` or `-exec`. To avoid this, since you're using bash, use its built-in recursive directory traversal feature instead of `find`.

```
shopt -s globstar
xgettext -j --from-code=UTF-8 -o "$TARGET/$LPATH/$POFILE" **/*.php
```

This way, if the concatenated file names go over the command line length limit, you'll get an error instead of a silently truncated file. Beware that in bash, `**/` traverses symbolic links to directories, not just directories. If this is a problem, either use ksh or zsh instead of bash, or use a different method.

With `find`, to avoid silently overwriting the output file over and over, write to standard output and redirect the whole `find` command to a file.

```
find . -name '*.php' -exec xgettext -j --from-code=UTF-8 {} + >"$TARGET/$LPATH/$POFILE"
```

`find` lists files in the order it finds them, it doesn't do any sorting. Neither sorting by name, nor sorting of directories before or after other files. (Directories are files. There isn't a separate list of subdirectories and of other files in a directory.)

`find` always lists the content of a directory immediately after the directory itself. With the option `-depth`, this is reversed: first the content of a directory, then the directory itself.

Answer (score 0):

If your target directory does not have any sub folders, you could try using `*` to expand all files ending in `.php` and iterate over them with `xgettext`.  This would remove the need for `find` and `xargs`.

```
for i in ./*.php; do
    xgettext -j --from-code=UTF-8 -o $TARGET/$LPATH/$POFILE $i
done
```

If you need to do a recursive search with `find`, you could iterate over the output of a sub shell containing your `find` command.

```
for i in $(find . -name '*.php'); do
    xgettext -j --from-code=UTF-8 -o $TARGET/$LPATH/$POFILE $i
done
```

Comment: Find is recursive, this solution is not. If you wanted to do a recursive glob, you need bash4+ and `globstar`, but beware of its broken symlink handling.